# How to check a value in a list and if its matching assigning it to a variable?

Tags: python, list, variables

The part of the code which I wrote:

```py
if level == "country":
    export_data = totalObjects
    for dummy in toys:
        object_list = []
        for items in export_data:
            item_type = items["type"]
            print(item_type)
            if (
                item_type == "A"
                or item_type == "AI"
                or item_type == "PR"
                or item_type == "PRO"
                or item_type == "DE"
            ):
                object_list.append({"id": items["id"]})
                publish_object = (
                    "Explore/" + foldername + "/" + dummy + "." + item_type + ".xml"
                )
```

The output is coming with error:

```py
{'count': 5, 'objects': []}
[{'id': '1FoTrNUISRwlGLAQ9kLOeK', 'path': 'Test', 'type': 'DLATE'}, {'id': 'erc6CJiluE2jzCxND2bLM1', 'path': 'Test', 'type': 'DLATE'}, {'id': 'aqXPJtbQU8ofNxMgfxr7Wk', 'path': 'Test', 'type': 'MT'}, {'id': '8UBPdSfpGHLbwuMbvPWPwQ', 'path': 'Test', 'type': 'PRO'}, {'id': '3vkmrppWY6WbZW8le0ZTWl', 'path': 'Test', 'type': 'Project'}]
DLATE
DLATE
MT
PRO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "publish.py", line 80, in <module>
    publish_object= "Explore/" + foldername + "/" + dummy + "." + item_type + ".xml"
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

I need the output to be:

```
publish_object= "Explore/" + foldername + "/" + dummy + "." + PRO + ".xml"
```

The `PRO` value should be assigned in since it matches the condition.

Comment: Can you show what `foldername` and `map` are?

Comment: `map` is a function in python. Avoid using reserved words for variables.

Comment: Both are variables, we will be passing single string values for that in inputs.

Comment: What type is `dummy`? Is it possible that could be a list?

Comment: item_type is coming as list and you can see its getting printed. So , its unable to take it and match with the conditions and fetch the publish_object